# Devise routing issues with admin role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to add Devise to an existing Rails 3.2.16 app.

I have the basics working, but I'd like to create an admin role that is able to edit any user profile without entering a password.

I used the code from **Option 2 - Adding an admin attribute** in the [Devise Wiki "Add An Admin Role" section](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-an-Admin-role) to set up the admin role.

My routes.rb has this:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }

  scope "/admin" do
      resources :users
  end
```

This gives me the following routes

```
new_user_session     GET     /users/sign_in(.:format)      devise/sessions#new
user_session         POST    /users/sign_in(.:format)      devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)     devise/sessions#destroy
user_password        POST    /users/password(.:format)     devise/passwords#create
new_user_password    GET     /users/password/new(.:format) devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password   GET     /users/password/edit(.:format)devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT     /users/password(.:format)     devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET /users/cancel(.:format)       registrations#cancel
user_registration    POST    /users(.:format)              registrations#create
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)      registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET   /users/edit(.:format)         registrations#edit
                      PUT    /users(.:format)              registrations#update
                      DELETE /users(.:format)              registrations#destroy
admin_edit_user       GET    /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format) users/registrations#edit
users                 GET    /admin/users(.:format)        users#index
                      POST   /admin/users(.:format)        users#create
new_user              GET    /admin/users/new(.:format)    users#new
edit_user             GET    /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
user                  GET    /admin/users/:id(.:format)     users#show
                      PUT    /admin/users/:id(.:format)     users#update
                      DELETE /admin/users/:id(.:format)     users#destroy
```

The user views (devise/registrations/edit, etc) are hooked up correctly and work just fine, but the admin views are all pulled from the users folder (users/edit, etc), which means they bypass Devise.

For instance, my admin user edit form should probably have some variation on this in the form_for:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

but that code doesn't pull in any of the user data (all form fields are empty). The only way I can get it to show up is with the old code:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

Which then uses the update method from my users_controller, NOT from the Devise registrations_controller.

I've tried lots of variations on the routes because that seems to be key, but non of my attempts have worked. Help?

Comment: The error is that my admin view pages don't use the right controller and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your `form_for` helper to properly route your request through Devise, you need to declare your `admin/users` resource routes as Devise routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }

scope "/admin" do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }
end
```

You'll continue to retain Devise functionality while being able to utilize the `admin` namespace for authorization purposes.

Comment: Actually, now I have another problem - my standard routes don't work in the admin namespace. `admin/users/:id/edit` gave an error so I added `match '/users/:id/edit',   to: 'registrations#edit', as: 'admin_edit_user'` to the admin namespace. Then I got an `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` error in RegistrationsController#edit so I added an edit method to my registrations_controller to define @user, but that makes no difference.

Comment: Okay, nevermind, I'm just going to roll back and get rid of Devise. It's causing way more problems than it's solving.

Comment: The problem you're witessing is urelated to routes. If this answer helped address your original issue, which I would contend it has, you should consider accepting it as correct.